# $(1+y^2)dx - (\sqrt{1+y^2} \cos(y) -xy)dy=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the problem is, convert the given differential equation to a linear equation and solve it.

$(1+y^2)dx - (\sqrt{1+y^2} \cos(y) -xy)dy=0 $

so I factored from $\sqrt{1+y^2}$ and now we have:

$\sqrt{1+y^2}(dx - ( \cos(y) -xy/\sqrt{1+y^2}))dy=0 $

and now I take $\sqrt{1+y^2}=u$ and then we have $yy'=uu'$.

but I can't continue. I don't know what to do with $\cos y$, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we divide by $(1+y^2)\,dy$, we get the linear equation
$$
\frac{dx(y)}{dy}+\frac{xy}{1+y^2}-\frac{\cos y}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=0. 
$$ 
Its integrating factor is
$$
\mu(y)= \exp\left(\int \frac{y}{1+y^2}\,dy\right)=\sqrt{1+y^2},
$$
hence we obtain
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}\sqrt{1+y^2}+\frac{xy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}-\cos y=0
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\left(x\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)=\cos y
$$
and
$$
x\sqrt{1+y^2}=\sin y+C.
$$

Comment: oh I forgot that I can use $dx/dy$. thanks a lot.